# inverse function to parametrisation of unit circle

Tags: calculus

I was asked to prove that the inverse function of the function $f$ isn't continuous.

$f: [0,2\pi)\rightarrow S^1$; $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$

$S^1$ denotes the circle of radius one centered in the origin.

I don't understand what the inverse function is.... The natural construction for me would be $f^{-1}(x,y)=\arccos(x)$ for $-1\leq x\leq 1$, $y\geq 0$ and $f^{-1}(x,y)=\arccos(x)+\pi$ for $-1\leq x\leq 1$, $y< 0$. Is this right?

Comment: You don't need to find a formula for the inverse function to show that it isn't continuous. Think about compactness...

Comment: But, I believe you want $f^{-1}(x,y)=2\pi-\arccos x$ for $y<0$.

Comment: Alternatively, think about *sequential* continuity of the inverse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. You want $f^{-1}(x,y)=2\pi-\arccos x$ for $y<0$.

To show that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous, show that it isn't continuous at the point $(1,0)$. Note that in any neighborhood of $(1,0)$ in $S^1$, there are points as close together as you like that get mapped to points that are not close to each other (one to a point near $t=0$ and one to a point near $t=2\pi$).

Alternatively, you could use the fact that $S^1$ is compact, while $[0,2\pi)$ isn't.